# which one is faster/easier in sorting? Array or linked list?

Tags: c

I am coding a project that need to store data either using array or linked list. Later on, the data has to be sorted. I feel like coding array is easier for sorting because we simply swap. For linked List we have to worry(and code) about the pointer and accessing each element is more expensive than array. Am I right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends heavily on your sorting algorithm and what you are sorting.  The cost of traversing a linked list is certainly higher than indexing an element in an array.  However, if your sorting algorithm involves shifting elements, this can be done in constant time in a linked list (whereas in an array it must be done element by element, copying each one).  Swapping elements in a linked list is also constant time (just change the pointers), whereas in an array it will be copying elements (maybe also constant time, depending on your data).

For a set of integers you want to sort using quicksort, it's probably faster to use an array; for a set of large structures you want to sort using selection sort, a linked list will be faster.

Then, there is the question of how you access elements.  If your intention in sorting was to access the elements later on by binary search, you'd definitely want to use an array (as binary search is usually slower than linear search on linked lists, unless the linked list is something like a balanced B-tree).

Comment: Nice general answer for a general question. +1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of sort you'll implement, you'll likely want random access to the elements in your collection.  With that in mind, an array is indeed a better choice.

I'll go ahead and guess this is a school/learning project (or else you'd be using pre-existing sort functions, wouldn't you), so the sorting algorithm you choose will have an impact on this decision.

Typically, the fastest sort is quicksort (or mergesort), which benefits from random access (therefore arrays).  Your idea about swapping is good too.  Usually you want to sort in place and avoid allocating extra memory.

Comment: Mergesort is quite efficient with linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this method (depends on what you are doing) but you can sort as you go with a linked-list tree if you know the sorting criteria.

Say it is numbers:

```
struct treeNode {
  struct treeNode* greater;
  struct treeNode* lesser;
  int myValue;
};
```

It is probably the most difficult to create an algorithm for (you will have to push nodes when certain intermediate values occur)... Depends how much you like to use recursion and helper functions.

Comment: That is not a linked list, that is a binary search tree.

Comment: @BillyONeal Sigh. Semantics. Same effect.

Comment: Erm, no, not semantics. A linked list and a binary search tree are very different structures used to solve very different problems. An array and linked list are as similar as a binary search tree and a linked list are.

Comment: @BillyOneal *I don't care if you call it a bamboozle*, it is a complex of linked nodes that can be sorted during run time.

Comment: @BillyONeal: It looks exactly like a doubly linked list to me (except for the structure names, which could've been "next" and "previous" instead)

Comment: Assuming it was a binary tree, insertion into a binary tree is among the simplest algorithms there are, and moreover can be seen as a special case of finding in a binary tree.

Comment: @FalconKirtaran Considering the question asks which is easier to implement, an **array** or **linked-list**, I think it is safe to assume this is a far more challenging design. Difficulty is relative.

Comment: This is indeed the case.